# How can i verify text present in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium

I have a form to check code Order in which I put "phone number" to search.
In a result list, I use `verifyTextPresent` to verify the value, but it fails.

Here is my link https://ventomarme55.bizwebvietnam.net/apps/kiem-tra-don-hang
and here my code:

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>https://ventomarme55.bizwebvietnam.net/apps/kiem-tra-don-hang</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>name=CheckType</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=PhoneNumber</td>
    <td>0987610597</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//button[@class='btn pull-right']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyTextPresent</td>
    <td>Số điện thoại: 0987610597</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Passed yay]

Use Value for input

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/apps/kiem-tra-don-hang</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=PhoneNumber</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=PhoneNumber</td>
    <td>4141414</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForValue</td>
    <td>id=PhoneNumber</td>
    <td>4141414</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyValue</td>
    <td>id=PhoneNumber</td>
    <td>4141414</td>
</tr>
```